# Convert unknown Object to Boolean

Tags: java, casting

I have an array map of `Map <String,Object>`. `Object` would be a simple type (`String`, `Integer`, `Boolean`, ...).

I'm trying to do something like

```
Boolean isSet = (Boolean) metaMap.get("is_set");
if (isSet) ...
```

`metaMap.get("is_set")` may not be set, so it can return null; or it is set but it may be using `0/1` `true/false` or `"true"/"false"`.

How do I convert all of these cases to a boolean?

I realize there is the `if/else` solution of using `instanceof`. I'm wondering if there is a simpler solution.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It sounds like you should really be using a dedicated class with fields instead of a `Map`.

Comment: If it really can be encoded as `0/1` and `"true"/"false"`, then I think the only way you have is to write some explicit code `parseBooleanFromObject` and specify there you real logic. Or it might be that 4castle is right and you are trying to apply totally wrong (non-Java) solution to your bigger problem.

Comment: Comment: "String, Integer, Boolean" are *not* primitive types

Comment: Comment 2: if you do: `Boolean isSet = (Boolean) metaMap.get("is_set");` and `is_set` is `null` (either set in `metaMap` to `null` or is not in `metaMap`) - you'll get NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Since you gave little information, I'm going to assume you have full control of the code - in particular the creation of the array.

Instead of using `Map<String, T>` in the array, create and use an interface with methods similar to the one below and derive the classes `StringMetaMap`, `IntegerMetaMap` etc. from it.

```
public interface MetaMap
{
 // returns true, if property is contained
 public boolean hasProperty(String property);

 // returns non-null value of property or throws an exception
 public boolean getPropertyOrThrow(String property) throws IllegalArgumentException;

 // returns null or property value (use methods above if you want to avoid null values)
 public Boolean getProperty(String property);
}
```

The classes encapsulate how they encode boolean values and allow for easy handling through the interface.

Comment: Since Java 8, `Map<K,V>` has a `getOrDefault(key, default)` method

Answer (score -3):

Why not just use map.entrySet().Stream.filter(e -> e != null).collect() to create a map which filters out nulls.

Comment: Object will not be null when its false